# How to print the output of tree to pdf without losing the color?

Tags: command-line, pdf, tree, ansi

I use the following command to print a directory structure to a file:

```
tree -h somepath/ > tree_of_somepath.txt
```

`tree` gives a nice colorized output on the terminal, but as expected this cannot be redirected to a text file. I would like to print the output of `tree` to a pdf file and preserve the color.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't need the color (as the OP does), you can still get usable tree output using `tree -n -d --charset unicode > file`. It's definitely not as pretty, but I use it with a monochrome laser printer when I'm herding my data files, etc..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Install the following dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install aha wkhtmltopdf
   ```
2. Save your `tree` command output to html with [`aha`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/aha.1.html):

   ```
   tree -C -h | aha > foo.html
   ```

   From the [`tree`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/tree.1.html) man page, `-C` forces colorization:

   ```
       -C     Turn colorization on always, using built-in color defaults
              if the LS_COLORS environment variable is not set. Useful to
              colorize output to a pipe.
   ```
3. Finally export the html to pdf with [`wkhtmltopdf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/wkhtmltopdf.1.html):

   ```
   wkhtmltopdf foo.html foo.pdf
   ```

---

Example:

```
cd /tmp
tree -C -h | aha > foo.html
wkhtmltopdf foo.html foo.pdf
xdg-open foo.pdf
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, though I omitted the --black to save some toner, when it lands on paper ;)

Comment: @Bruni Good idea :) Let me edit the answer

Comment: $ wkhtmltopdf foo.html foo.pdf
wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server